# Install recommended packages of an already installed package with apt

Tags: software-installation, apt

I previously installed a package with the `--no-install-recommends` and am now missing some functionality due to these packages missing. Is there a way to install these packages with an `apt-get` command without completely uninstalling it (as this will remove a plethora of dependent packages as well)?

I know I can use `apt-cache depends *packagename* | grep Recommends` to get a list of these packages, which I can then manually install and manually set to autoinstalled. However I would like to know whether you can do this automatically with apt-get.

Answer (score 5):

With a little bit `awk`:

```
apt-cache depends YOUR_PACKAGE | \
    awk '/Recommends:/ {system("sudo apt-get install "$2"; sudo apt-mark auto "$2)}'
```

Comment: But this is not recursive, contrary to the automatic installation of recommended packages.